# How to read multiple text files from a folder and append it to a new file in java using io package?

Tags: java, io

How to read multiple text files from a folder and append it to a new file in java using io package? In that folder there might be files other than text files, I have tried to solve the question it is working fine. Is there any easier method to do this instead of this long code, Please suggest if any
    package practice;

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadWriteFiles {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        String inpath="C:/Users/sr01407/Desktop/test";
        String outpath="C:/Users/sr01407/Desktop/numbers.txt";
        File Folder=new File(inpath);
        File Files[];
        Files=Folder.listFiles();
        /*for(int j=0;j<Files.length;j++){
            System.out.println(Files[j]);
        }*/
        File OutFile = new File(outpath);
        // if File doesn't exists, then create it
        if (!OutFile.exists()) {
            OutFile.createNewFile();
        }
     for(int i=0;i<Files.length;i++){ 
         String FileName=Files[i].getName();

         if(FileName.endsWith("txt")){
             // System.out.println(FileName);
    BufferedReader streamIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Files[i].toString()));

    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(OutFile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
    BufferedWriter streamOut= new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
    String count;
    while ((count = streamIn.readLine()) != null) {
        streamOut.write(count);
        streamOut.newLine();
        }
        streamOut.flush();
        streamOut.close();
    }}


}
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing (with a full error message and stack trace where appropriate), and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.

Comment: Better you post this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if it is already working.

Answer (score 2):

As the concrete Java version is not specified, let's assume it is Java 8. As you mentioned you have to use `java.io` package, let's assume it is not allowed to use fancy methods from classes like `java.nio.file.Files` or `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`. In this case I would propose a bit shorter way to do it.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final File directory = new File("C:/Users/sr01407/Desktop/test");
    final File[] files = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".txt"));
    if (files == null) {
        throw new IOException("the file " + directory + " is not a directory");
    }
    try (final BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/sr01407/Desktop/numbers.txt", true))) {
        for (final File file : files) {
            try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.write(line);
                    output.newLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main differences from what you proposed are the usage of the `File#listFiles(FilenameFilter)` to list and filter the files and the try-with-resources statement.